# How do I switch views with Polymer's paper-tabs?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am trying to create a switchable view in Polymer's `<paper-tabs>`.

```
<paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}">
  <paper-tab>1</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>2</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>3</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
<iron-pages selected="{{selected}}">
  <div>Page 1</div>
  <div>Page 2</div>
  <div>Page 3</div>
</iron-pages>

<script>
  var pages= document.querySelected('iron-pages');
  var tabs=document.querySelected('paper-tabs');
  tabs.addEventListener('iron-selected', function(e) {
    pages.selected=tabs.selected;
  });
</script>
```

With the above code, the `<paper-tab>` itself is working, but the views are not changing on tab selection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/41295628/6277151

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have included iron-pages using `<link rel="import" href="path of iron-pages">.`

Answer (score 0):

- `document.querySelected` is a typo. You probably meant [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- You don't need to imperatively set the selected page because you're already using data bindings, which keeps the `<iron-pages>.selected` and `<paper-tabs>.selected` in sync for you automatically.
- It looks like you have a binding outside of a custom element (e.g., in your `index.html`), which requires a [`dom-bind`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/dom-bind) template, like this:

  ```
  <!-- index.html -->
  <body>
    <template is="dom-bind" id="t">
      <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}">...</paper-tabs>
      <iron-pages selected="{{selected}}">...</iron-pages>
    </template>
    <script>
      var t = document.getElementById('t');
      t.selected = 0;
    </script>
  </body>
  ```

  You could also define a custom element in a `dom-module` to avoid the `dom-bind` template in your main document.

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
</head>
<body>
  <template is="dom-bind" id="t">
    <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}">
      <paper-tab>1</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab>2</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab>3</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>
    <iron-pages selected="{{selected}}">
      <div>Page 1</div>
      <div>Page 2</div>
      <div>Page 3</div>
    </iron-pages>
  </template>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("WebComponentsReady", function() {
      // initialize selected tab
      var t = document.getElementById("t");
      t.selected = 0;
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/xRoBVX?editors=1010)

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped. You're Awesome! :)

Comment: @MridulAdvani No problem :)